# Error on an unexisting field after uninstalling a module

Tags: postgresql, module, odoo, odoo-10

I created a module where I overrided the create method on res.partner model and res.user model:

```
class Partner(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'
    is_commercial = fields.Boolean(string= 'is Commercial')

class User(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.users'

    is_commercial = fields.Boolean(string= 'is Commercial')

    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        user = super(User, self).create(vals)
        user.partner_id.active = user.active
        user.partner_id.is_commercial = user.is_commercial
        if user.partner_id.company_id:
            user.partner_id.write({'company_id': user.company_id.id})
        return user

    @api.multi
    @api.onchange('is_commercial')
    def onchange_is_commercial(self):
        for partner in self.partner_id:
            if self.is_commercial == True:
                partner.write({'is_commercial': True}) 
            else: 
                if self.is_commercial == False:
                    partner.write({'is_commercial': False})
```

This code works well and now I uninstalled this module and went back to sales -> Customers. I got this error:

```
File "D:\Projet\erp\odoo\osv\expression.py", line 821, in parse
raise ValueError("Invalid field %r in leaf %r" % (left, str(leaf)))
ValueError: Invalid field u'is_commercial' in leaf "<osv.ExtendedLeaf: (u'is_commercial', u'=', True) on res_partner (ctx: )>"
```

I'm working with odoo10, postgresql-9.5

Comment: Do you have the `is_commercial` field referenced in a view somewhere outside of your module? For example, if you manually updated the view through the Debug/Developer Tools, then it's still trying to load this in the view but it can't find the field in the database.

Comment: yes I have this field in res.user and res.partner models in base module. The only way till now to fix my problem is by creating new database.

Comment: Can you install the module and uninstall without issue on a different database? If so, it must be an issue with a view trying to display the field for a model that doesn't have the field present.